# Projectile Motion Question About Angle

Tags: projectile-motion

> An object which is projected from the ground with an angle of $\theta$ passes two walls(without touching) within its motion.The wall which has a height of '**a**' is situated in a distance of '**v**' from the projected place and the other wall  which has a height of '**b**' is situated in a distance of '**a**' from the first wall. *Find a expression with a and b for the  $\tan$ value of the $\theta$*.

[image: Parabolic Trajectory]

I tried to find the $\theta$,

$\rightarrow  s = ut \\ v=u\cos\theta.t_{1}\\$

$\uparrow s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^{2}\\
a=u\sin\theta\times\frac{v}{ucos\theta}-\frac{g}{2}\times\frac{v^{2}}{u^{2}\cos^{2}\theta}\\
a=v \tan\theta-\frac{gv^{2}\sec^{2}}{2u^{2}}$

$\rightarrow s=ut\

v+a = u\cos\theta\times t_{2}$

$\uparrow s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^{2}\\
b=u\sin\theta\times\frac{v+a}{u\cos\theta}-\frac{g}{2}\times\frac{(v+a)^{2}}{u^{2}\cos^{2}\theta}\\
b=(v+a)\tan\theta-\frac{g(v+a)^{2}\sec^{2}\theta}{2u^{2}}$

I don't see a way to find the $\theta$.Please help.

Comment: @Aakash Kumar What equation?

Comment: $y= xtan \theta -\frac{gx^2}{2u^2Cos^2 \theta} $

Comment: @ Aakash Kumar If I knew I woludn't ask this question

Comment: @ Aakash Kumar No

Comment: @Nimantha I slightly changed the picture, hope  ok. Else feel free to delete/restore.

Comment: You have taken $u$ as distance and also as initial velocity .

Comment: @Nimantha Are you allowed to express $\tan{\theta}$ as a function of $a$, $b$, and $v$, or do you have to eliminate $v$ from the final expression?

Comment: The trouble is I'm not sure how you can eliminate so many unknowns. The parabola is $y(x) = Sx^2 + Tx$, because it passes through the origin. You know that $y(v) = a$, and $y(a+v) = y(y(v)+v) = b$.  I don't see that you can eliminate $S$ and $v$ to get an expression for $T(a,b)$.

Answer (score 2):

Do not complicate things. Just handle a parabola through the origin .

$$ y= A x -B x^2 $$
$ u= v+a $

Point $(v,a)$
$$ a = Av - Bv^2 \tag{1}$$
Point $ (u,b)$
$$ b = Au- Bu^2 \tag{2}$$

Solve (1),(2) for $ A,B $. You can take it further.

Slope is obtained by differentiating $y(x)$ and finding derivative at (0,0)

$$ dy/dx = A . $$

Comment: Nicely simplified (+1)